# refused to connect after remove another website in my server

Tags: centos7, digital-ocean

My website is bannedadsense.com, i was able to access it yesterday. Now I can't acccess to it from my laptop using chrome and firefox.

This is the notice from chrome:

> bannedadsense.com refused to connect.

But ping bannedadsense.com is still running good.

> [dang@centos-512mb-nyc3 ~]$ ping bannedadsense.com PING
>   bannedadsense.com (45.55.213.4) 56(84) bytes of data. 64 bytes from
>   centos-512mb-nyc3-01 (45.55.213.4): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.062 m
>   s 64 bytes from centos-512mb-nyc3-01 (45.55.213.4): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64
>   time=0.137 m                     s 64 bytes from centos-512mb-nyc3-01
>   (45.55.213.4): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.140 m                     s 64
>   bytes from centos-512mb-nyc3-01 (45.55.213.4): icmp_seq=4 ttl=64
>   time=0.067 m                     s 64 bytes from centos-512mb-nyc3-01
>   (45.55.213.4): icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.103 m                     s 64
>   bytes from centos-512mb-nyc3-01 (45.55.213.4): icmp_seq=6 ttl=64
>   time=0.124 ms 64 bytes from centos-512mb-nyc3-01 (45.55.213.4):
>   icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=0.078 ms 64 bytes from centos-512mb-nyc3-01
>   (45.55.213.4): icmp_seq=8 ttl=64 time=0.133 ms 64 bytes from
>   centos-512mb-nyc3-01 (45.55.213.4): icmp_seq=9 ttl=64 time=0.139 ms 64
>   bytes from centos-512mb-nyc3-01 (45.55.213.4): icmp_seq=10 ttl=64
>   time=0.127 ms 64 bytes from centos-512mb-nyc3-01 (45.55.213.4):
>   icmp_seq=11 ttl=64 time=0.103 ms 64 bytes from centos-512mb-nyc3-01
>   (45.55.213.4): icmp_seq=12 ttl=64 time=0.191 ms

Accessing to ftp is still good.

I don't know what is the problem.

Checked from proxy:

> The requested resource could not be loaded. libcurl returned the
>   error: Failed to connect to bannedadsense.com port 80: Connection
>   refused

I have stopped firewall from the server. But the problem is still there.

---

I see the problem now:
I can't restart apache, the problem is here.

> sudo apachectl restart

Please help me, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem now: I can't restart apache, the problem is here.

> sudo apachectl restart
>   apachectl status

this is a part of the result from the command line:

Dec 22 05:31:55 centos-512mb-nyc3-01 httpd[728]: (2)No such file or directory: AH02291: Cannot access directory '/var/www/xosopowerball.net/' for error log ...et.conf:1
Dec 22 05:31:55 centos-512mb-nyc3-01 httpd[728]: (2)No such file or directory: AH02291: Cannot access directory '/var/www/xosomegamillions.com/' for error l...om.conf:1

And i only create new 2 folders with the name are xosopowerball.net and xosomegamillions.com and restart apache again, and all problems fixed done.

---

New solution:
remove files in /etc/httpd/sites-available/ and /etc/httpd/sites-enabled/ and the restart. And then you can remove 2 folders in /var/www. I created them when i setup the virtual hosts, check here [Create New Virtual Host Files](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-centos-7?utm_content=how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-centos-7#step-four-%E2%80%94-create-new-virtual-host-files)

Thank you for reading my problem.